# Jenkinsfile deploy using docker containers add rollback to run previous stable image

Tags: docker, jenkins, deployment

I have the following stage in a Jenkins pipeline:

```
stage('Continuous deployment') {
            stages {
                stage('Build and Push Docker Image') {
                    steps {
                        echo 'Build and Pushing image...'
                        script {
                            deployContainer(env.DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME)
                        }
                        echo 'Image pushed'
                    }
                }
                stage('Run Docker Image') {
                    steps {
                        echo 'Running image...'
                         script {
                            removeContainer(env.DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME)
                            runCmd("docker run -d -p 3002:3000 --restart unless-stopped --name ${env.DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME} ${env.DOCKER_REPO}/${env.DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME}")
                         }
                        echo 'Running'
                    }
                    post {
                        failure {
                            runCmd("docker run -d -p 3002:3000 --restart unless-stopped --name ${env.DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME} ${env.DOCKER_REPO}/${env.DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME}")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I was expecting that if the run fails it would run with a previously pushed image, but it does not.

Also, the remove funtion does not appear to be running as expected, since it does not stop and remove the running container.

Am I missing something? :(

---

Note: the functions bellow are the ones used in the stage.

```
def runCmd(String cmd) {
    if (isUnix()) {
        sh(script: cmd, returnStatus: true)
    } else {
        bat(script: cmd, returnStatus: true)
    }
}

def deployContainer(imageName) {
    // Set up dockerhub_credentials in Jenkins as a global credential
    docker.withRegistry('https://registry.hub.docker.com', 'dockerhub_credentials') {
        def customImage = docker.build("${env.DOCKER_REPO}/${imageName}:${env.BUILD_NUMBER}")
        // Push image do dockerhub
        customImage.push()
        //customImage.imageName("${env.DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME}:latest")
    }
}

def removeContainer(containerName) {
    // Check if the blue container exists
    def containerExists = runCmd("docker ps -q -f name=${containerName}")
    if(containerExists) {
        // Stop container
        runCmd("docker stop ${containerName}")
        // Remove container
        runCmd("docker rm ${containerName}")
    }
}
```

Issue 1: Rollback message

```
runCmd("docker run -d -p 3002:3000 --restart unless-stopped --name ${env.DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME} ${env.DOCKER_REPO}/${env.DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME}")
```

> C:\Users\xxx\.jenkins\workspace\xxxx>docker run -d -p 3002:3000
> --restart unless-stopped --name containerx xxxx/imagex  Unable to find image 'xxxx/imagex' locally

Issue 2: Remove container did not run properly therefore new could not be initialized

```
removeContainer(env.DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME)
```

> C:\Users\xxx\.jenkins\workspace\xxxx>docker run -d --restart
> unless-stopped --name containerx -p 3002:3000
> xxxx/imagex:90  docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict.
> The container name "/containerx" is already in use by container
> "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy".
> You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that
> name. See 'docker run --help'.

- This is for a school project!

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE!

.

Comment: You mean the `failure` block is never reached even if the `Run Docker Image` stage fails?

Comment: well, it reads the stage, but it does not run the container with the image because it says it cannot find it locally, from what I read it should download the last image if i do not specify any tag, for example using the image `xxxx/imagex` instead of `xxxx/imagex:yy`

Comment: This would be easier with the Docker plugin methods as opposed to e.g. `runCmd`.

Comment: @MatthewSchuchard sorry to ask, but can you provide an example plz? I'm really new to this so i get easly lost in what I find. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Am I missing something? :(

The current design of the pipeline does not allow to safely run the `failure` block because the state of the system is undetermined.
Consider the following cases:

1. `removeContainer()` script executed successfully, subsequent `runCmd` failed
2. `removeContainer()` script failed, because `runCmd("docker ps -q -f name=${containerName}")` returned non-zero (I'm not 100% sure Groovy will fail here though but everything is possible with Jenkins)
3. `removeContainer()` script failed, because `runCmd("docker ps -q -f name=${containerName}")` returned 0 but subsequent `docker stop ${containerName}` failed
4. `removeContainer()` script failed, because `runCmd("docker ps -q -f name=${containerName}")` returned 0 but subsequent `docker rm ${containerName}` failed

These cases should be handled differently, but currently all of them are being remediated by the same `docker run` command (which in case #1 would be exactly the same as the one that failed).

On top of that, if Docker complains that it's unable to find the image locally, chances are that it wasn't able to find it on DockerHub at the first place. If you don't specify the tag, Docker will implicitly search for the `latest` tag, and according to the pipeline code, it hasn't been pushed to the registry. At least it is unclear whether `${env.DOCKER_REPO}/${imageName}:${env.BUILD_NUMBER}` equals to `${env.DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME}`.

To sum up - Docker will work as you expected once you add `customImage.push('latest')` as mentioned in [Using Docker with Pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#building-containers) part of Jenkins documentation. But in this case you will end up with the same failing container being restarted over and over again, because by the time of `failure` invocation the `latest` tag will not refer to the previously functional image anymore.

> // Check if the blue container exists

If my assumption that this is a simulation of a [blue-green deployment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue%E2%80%93green_deployment) is correct, the actual process works in a different way (just key points, oversimplified):

- a new container gets started
- if it works as expected, the traffic gets switched to the new one, and the old one gets stopped
- if it doesn't work as expected, the old container remains running, and the new one gets stopped.

You can try to reproduce this without switching the traffic - just use different port numbers, container names, and (most importantly) image names.